# Get destination URL of a link from edealinfo.co.uk in PHP

Tags: php, url, curl

The URL that I'm working with is: http://www.edealinfo.co.uk/deals/redirect.php?id=k9OTxOWl25NiuN3KuZWIlFeagbK3aZo%3

I already tried:

```
    $ch = curl_init("http://www.edealinfo.co.uk/deals/redirect.php?id=k9OTxOWl25NiuN3KuZWIlFeagbK3aZo%3");   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($data = curl_getinfo($ch));
    echo $data["url"];
```

I also tried:

```
print_r(get_headers("http://www.edealinfo.co.uk/deals/redirect.php?id=k9OTxOWl25NiuN3KuZWIlFeagbK3aZo%3"));
```

Without any luck. Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

That URL is not redirecting with a header, rather using an auto-submitting form in the returned HTML. This is why you're not having any luck with the headers.

```
Loading...<form action='/cgi-bin/amazonsp.cgi?B006U98G74' method='post' name='frm'></form><script>document.frm.submit();</script>
```

You'll need to parse the document body.

Comment: Ok, I see. And how could I parse the document body?